# 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated error using Mailkit when connecting on port 25

Tags: .net, vb.net, smtp, mailkit

Below is the telnet session information:
[image]

This means that the Exchange receive connectors are configured correctly; Also this relay is used by dozens of other applications

But When I try to send email using below code:

```
SmtpHost.Connect(Server, Port, SecureSocketOptions.None) 'Port is 25 here
 Dim msg As New MailMessage()
    Try
        msg.From = New MailAddress(Me.from)
        msg.Subject = Subject
        RecipientList = RecipientList.Replace(",", ";")
        Dim recipients As String() = RecipientList.Split(";")
        For Each recipient As String In recipients
            msg.To.Add(recipient)
        Next
        msg.Body = Body
        Me.SmtpHost.Send(Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        // Exception Handling code 
    Finally
        msg.Dispose()
        msg = Nothing
    End Try
```

I get the below error:

```
5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
```

I also verified that Anonymous was enabled here:  Exchange Management Console > Server Configuration > Hub Transport > Default Receive Connector > Properties  as several articles online pointed to that as being the issue.

It would be a great help if anyone can help me and let me know what I might be missing here.

Comment: For some reason the SMTP server is requiring you to authenticate. Maybe it's the IP address you are connecting from or maybe it's the `MAIL FROM` address.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem using mailkit but using dependency injection.
Setting the `RequiresAuthentication` to true solved it.

```
      services.AddFluentEmail(mailConfig["address"])
              .AddMailKitSender(new FluentEmail.MailKitSmtp.SmtpClientOptions() {
                Server = mailConfig["smtpServer"],
                Port = smtpPort,
                Password = ...,
                User = mailConfig["address"],
                RequiresAuthentication = true,
                UseSsl = true,
              });
    }
```